# Setterm blink issue

Tags: linux, terminal, kde

I'm using Debian with KDE version 4.14.2 and I'm trying to make Terminal cursor to blink, like in Ubuntu. Using `setterm --blink on` makes **username and hostname** to blink until next command, but nothing happens to cursor.

Is there any way solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the "Terminal" means "konsole" in your case, since that is KDE's default terminal.

Go to `Settings` -> `Edit Current Profile` -> `Advanced`, here you'll find the cursor settings (shape and blinking).

There is an escape sequence to dynamically change the value, supported by various terminal emulators, but apparently not by konsole: `echo -ne '\e[0 q'` with the number ranging from 0 to 6; see `DECSCUSR` at http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html.